# how to minimize the popup of command prompt when batch file is running in loop?

Tags: batch-file

```
@ECHO OFF
C:
for /L %%a in (1,0,10) do (
    echo This is iteration %%a
    start "" "C:\Desktop\fast\JumpTracker.exe"  -COM7
    TIMEOUT 1
)
```

When I run this code it's running after 1 second interval and also pop a window of command prompt. The batch file is running in a **(for loop)** , I want to minimize the command prompt but batch file should be in  running condition. Is it possible? can any one help me?

Comment: Does `start /b` work to prevent the creation of the popup window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained by @bgoldst:

> Does start /b work to prevent the creation of the popup window?

Therefore the result should be:

```
@ECHO OFF
C:
for /L %%a in (1,0,10) do (
    echo This is iteration %%a
    start /b "" "C:\Desktop\fast\JumpTracker.exe"  -COM7
    TIMEOUT 1
)
```

Comment: ([Comment converted to a community wiki answer.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments))